# Recessed lighting not lighting up

Tags: electrical

So I bough 6 LED recessed lights from a flea market today.  $30 so why not.  Each one has the log socket adapter so I tried all six on a socket and only one works.

Sooooooooo. With the other five, what is next?  Should I take the connector off each light and wire each from some source to see if they light up?

Comment: It's probably not the connection that's gone bad, but sure, try it and see what happens.

Comment: It is almost always true that you get what you pay for.

Comment: What can go wrong, indeed? LED lights have, at their heart, a driver and the LED emitter. The emitter is pretty robust, and the driver isn't. So I think you bought the proverbial pig in the poke. But crack 'em open and see if you can figure anything out.

Comment: Welp, one works so that means I broke even.  If I can get the other five to work, then sweet.  Will crack one open and learn I guess

Comment: I agree, drivers are the weak link. Thing is, fixture makers usually don't make drivers. They buy them on the open market, and simply leave a compartment big enough for the commonly available ones.  So even if you have a driver problem, they're a few bucks on Amazon.

Comment: Are you sure they're screwed all the way in?  I've had issues with LED and compact fluorescent bulbs in recessed lights.  The newer bulbs are often wider in the area right above the metal threaded portion, and in some sockets this hits the top of the socket before the center terminal contacts the center of the socket.  This can sometimes be fixed by bending the socket's center terminal so it stickes out a bit more, but not always (obviously, do that only with the power verified to be off).  I have tried a few bulbs that can't be used in some of my sockets because of this.

Comment: Actually figured it out.  I took one a part and looked.  There are two tiny white connections.  They go from the circuit board to the LED itself.  Both connections are severed, and have to be soldered back together.